# Delete tags mwe and mwes?

Tags: discussion, tags

I came across a question with the tag `mwe` today, and I deleted that tag because there were no other questions with the same tag and I find it very misleading in the context of stackexchange (*Minimal Working Example* comes immediately to my mind).

I see also that there are two questions to the tag `mwes` that is only slightly better.

I suggest to delete both tags. If a tag for multi word expressions is deemed useful, it should be verbose IMO, like `multi-word-expression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I retagged the questions. The old tags should get deleted by tomorrow according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags).